# Which is the best place to generate the script tag dynamically with json embedded before the page loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, json-ld

I am trying to add Json-LD data to some of my pages but I am confused with what path to take.

This is the flow:

So we have a controller action method where we create SEO-friendly URL and we return a view based on that.

```
public class SEOFriendlyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string queryString)
    { 
        //logic to return different views based on Product details/Blogs/Articles etc..
    }
}
```

Then on the angular front we have angular controller which makes an ajax call based on `Product details Id/BlogsId/Article Id` etc.

Now, my question is which is the appropriate place to implement the logic of generating the below script tag for Product details/Blogs/Articles etc:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Manu Sporny",
  "url": "http://manu.sporny.org/about/"
 }
```

I thought of doing it on the angular front where I will make a call to my controller, get the relevant Product details/Blogs/Articles data, generate the script tag with it then load the page but the problem is the page will get load before the script tag is rendered.

I just want to have my script tag ready before the page loads and rendered it but I am confused with which is the best place to generate the Script tag?

**Update:**
I am confused with whether I should create a Json-LD script tag with data from the database on the server-side or client-side?

If we go with the client-side then my concern is how to generate the JSON-LD script tag before the page loads because the data inside the script tag is coming from the database.

Comment: Ideally you want server side and have the json-ld present in the initial html. Some consumers don't run JavaScript. But Google and others do read rendered json-ld. Why are you concerned about it being done before load?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath because I will done it after the data is loaded then the script tag too will be generated after that. I believe google bots needs this Json data before the entire page is loaded. Right?

Comment: Google gives your page about 5 seconds to load content. If you use the Rich Result Test tool you will see if Google sees your SD.